# javascript array

Tags: javascript

whats the problem with that array?

```
var proImages = {
{img_1 : '3648119884.png',img_2 : '2737618597.png',img_3 : '1688333623.png'},
{img_1 : '8738764911.png',img_2 : '1367341638.png',img_3 : '9613419473.png'},
{img_1 : '0072066717.png',img_2 : '2516072491.png',img_3 : '1567853878.png'},
{img_1 : '2991559225.png',img_2 : '8333423763.png',img_3 : '8057162573.png'},
{img_1 : '7136719769.png',img_2 : '1881889542.png',img_3 : '5844323517.png'},
{img_1 : '7993931084.png',img_2 : '6991377670.png',img_3 : '3310663052.png'},
{img_1 : '3361259627.png',img_2 : '2221673184.png',img_3 : '9499134393.png'},
{img_1 : '7647189195.png',img_2 : '8252917294.png',img_3 : '5475029195.png'},
{img_1 : '4546336022.png',img_2 : '9378256077.png',img_3 : '5624264738.png'},
{img_1 : '5969572723.png',img_2 : '9878662191.png',img_3 : '9260704536.png'},
{img_1 : '5307173138.png',img_2 : '5915393636.png',img_3 : '0393696135.png'},
{img_1 : '3890469821.png',img_2 : '5722291935.png',img_3 : '1776314584.png'},
{img_1 : '5105921436.png',img_2 : '2969844375.png',img_3 : '0879713286.png'},
{img_1 : '8923771834.png',img_2 : '3176446381.png',img_3 : '4669049321.png'},
{img_1 : '7973191654.png',img_2 : '5472865178.png',img_3 : '7881294714.png'},
{img_1 : '0801773822.png',img_2 : '8424418951.png',img_3 : '1923419282.png'},
{img_1 : '0.png',img_2 : '0.png',img_3 : '0.png'}};
```

Comment: `answer = ["it","is","not","an","array","at","all"];`

Comment: not an array and not a valid object either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript all arrays are objects but not all objects are arrays - well sort of :).

You object as declared is invalid.

You can iterate an object as well as an object but it is done differently.  One issue is that this is not really even an object as declared.  SO you need to declare it differently.

Access example is included in each;

With an inner array: proImages.myobj[5].img_1

```
var proImages = {myobj:[        {
        img_1: '3648119884.png',
        img_2: '2737618597.png',
        img_3: '1688333623.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '8738764911.png',
        img_2: '1367341638.png',
        img_3: '9613419473.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0072066717.png',
        img_2: '2516072491.png',
        img_3: '1567853878.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '2991559225.png',
        img_2: '8333423763.png',
        img_3: '8057162573.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7136719769.png',
        img_2: '1881889542.png',
        img_3: '5844323517.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7993931084.png',
        img_2: '6991377670.png',
        img_3: '3310663052.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '3361259627.png',
        img_2: '2221673184.png',
        img_3: '9499134393.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7647189195.png',
        img_2: '8252917294.png',
        img_3: '5475029195.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '4546336022.png',
        img_2: '9378256077.png',
        img_3: '5624264738.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5969572723.png',
        img_2: '9878662191.png',
        img_3: '9260704536.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5307173138.png',
        img_2: '5915393636.png',
        img_3: '0393696135.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '3890469821.png',
        img_2: '5722291935.png',
        img_3: '1776314584.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5105921436.png',
        img_2: '2969844375.png',
        img_3: '0879713286.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '8923771834.png',
        img_2: '3176446381.png',
        img_3: '4669049321.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7973191654.png',
        img_2: '5472865178.png',
        img_3: '7881294714.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0801773822.png',
        img_2: '8424418951.png',
        img_3: '1923419282.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0.png',
        img_2: '0.png',
        img_3: '0.png'
    }
    ]
};
```

AS an array: proImages[5].img_2

```
var proImages = {myarray[
    {
        img_1: '3648119884.png',
        img_2: '2737618597.png',
        img_3: '1688333623.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '8738764911.png',
        img_2: '1367341638.png',
        img_3: '9613419473.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0072066717.png',
        img_2: '2516072491.png',
        img_3: '1567853878.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '2991559225.png',
        img_2: '8333423763.png',
        img_3: '8057162573.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7136719769.png',
        img_2: '1881889542.png',
        img_3: '5844323517.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7993931084.png',
        img_2: '6991377670.png',
        img_3: '3310663052.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '3361259627.png',
        img_2: '2221673184.png',
        img_3: '9499134393.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7647189195.png',
        img_2: '8252917294.png',
        img_3: '5475029195.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '4546336022.png',
        img_2: '9378256077.png',
        img_3: '5624264738.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5969572723.png',
        img_2: '9878662191.png',
        img_3: '9260704536.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5307173138.png',
        img_2: '5915393636.png',
        img_3: '0393696135.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '3890469821.png',
        img_2: '5722291935.png',
        img_3: '1776314584.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '5105921436.png',
        img_2: '2969844375.png',
        img_3: '0879713286.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '8923771834.png',
        img_2: '3176446381.png',
        img_3: '4669049321.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '7973191654.png',
        img_2: '5472865178.png',
        img_3: '7881294714.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0801773822.png',
        img_2: '8424418951.png',
        img_3: '1923419282.png'
    }, {
        img_1: '0.png',
        img_2: '0.png',
        img_3: '0.png'
    }
    ];
```

Or As a series of objects (well one really with inner objects: proImages.myobj4.img_2

```
var proImages = 
    {  myobj1: {img_1: '3648119884.png', img_2: '2737618597.png', img_3: '1688333623.png'
    }, myobj2: {img_1: '8738764911.png', img_2: '1367341638.png', img_3: '9613419473.png'
    }, myobj3: {img_1: '0072066717.png', img_2: '2516072491.png', img_3: '1567853878.png' 
    }, myobj4: {img_1: '2991559225.png', img_2: '8333423763.png', img_3: '8057162573.png'
    }, myobj5: {img_1: '7136719769.png', img_2: '1881889542.png', img_3: '5844323517.png'
    }, myobj6: {img_1: '7993931084.png', img_2: '6991377670.png', img_3: '3310663052.png'
    }, myobj7: {img_1: '3361259627.png', img_2: '2221673184.png', img_3: '9499134393.png' 
    }, myobj8: {img_1: '7647189195.png', img_2: '8252917294.png', img_3: '5475029195.png'
    }, myobj9: {img_1: '4546336022.png', img_2: '9378256077.png', img_3: '5624264738.png'
    }, myobj10: {img_1: '5969572723.png', img_2: '9878662191.png', img_3: '9260704536.png'
    }, myobj11: {img_1: '5307173138.png', img_2: '5915393636.png', img_3: '0393696135.png'
    }, myobj12: {img_1: '3890469821.png', img_2: '5722291935.png', img_3: '1776314584.png'
    }, myobj13: {img_1: '5105921436.png', img_2: '2969844375.png', img_3: '0879713286.png'
    }, myobj14: {img_1: '8923771834.png', img_2: '3176446381.png', img_3: '4669049321.png'
    }, myobj15: {img_1: '7973191654.png', img_2: '5472865178.png', img_3: '7881294714.png'
    }, myobj16: {img_1: '0801773822.png', img_2: '8424418951.png', img_3: '1923419282.png'
    }, myobj17: {img_1: '0.png',img_2: '0.png', img_3: '0.png'
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `[a,b,c,...]` to create an array in Javascript, and `{a:1, b:2, c:3, ...}` to create an Object (associative array).

```
var proImages = [    // <-----
{img_1 : '3648119884.png',img_2 : '2737618597.png',img_3 : '1688333623.png'},
...
{img_1 : '0.png',img_2 : '0.png',img_3 : '0.png'}];   // <------
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an array, but an object. Use `[` and `]` instead of `{` and `}`:

```
var proImages = [
{img_1 : '3648119884.png',img_2 : '2737618597.png',img_3 : '1688333623.png'},
{img_1 : '8738764911.png',img_2 : '1367341638.png',img_3 : '9613419473.png'},
{img_1 : '0072066717.png',img_2 : '2516072491.png',img_3 : '1567853878.png'},
{img_1 : '2991559225.png',img_2 : '8333423763.png',img_3 : '8057162573.png'},
{img_1 : '7136719769.png',img_2 : '1881889542.png',img_3 : '5844323517.png'},
{img_1 : '7993931084.png',img_2 : '6991377670.png',img_3 : '3310663052.png'},
{img_1 : '3361259627.png',img_2 : '2221673184.png',img_3 : '9499134393.png'},
{img_1 : '7647189195.png',img_2 : '8252917294.png',img_3 : '5475029195.png'},
{img_1 : '4546336022.png',img_2 : '9378256077.png',img_3 : '5624264738.png'},
{img_1 : '5969572723.png',img_2 : '9878662191.png',img_3 : '9260704536.png'},
{img_1 : '5307173138.png',img_2 : '5915393636.png',img_3 : '0393696135.png'},
{img_1 : '3890469821.png',img_2 : '5722291935.png',img_3 : '1776314584.png'},
{img_1 : '5105921436.png',img_2 : '2969844375.png',img_3 : '0879713286.png'},
{img_1 : '8923771834.png',img_2 : '3176446381.png',img_3 : '4669049321.png'},
{img_1 : '7973191654.png',img_2 : '5472865178.png',img_3 : '7881294714.png'},
{img_1 : '0801773822.png',img_2 : '8424418951.png',img_3 : '1923419282.png'},
{img_1 : '0.png',img_2 : '0.png',img_3 : '0.png'}];
```